# Split Data Frame Into N Data Frames Based On Column Names

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large data (thousands of columns) frame in which few columns have duplicate column name. Then, there are set of column names which have part of column name which is duplicate and another part of the same column name is not.

Using `R` and above two properties, I want to split all such columns into different data frames for further analysis. To achieve this I want to run following dynamic logic on data frame:

1. First: Find and `cbind()` duplicate column name columns into different data frames. If 10 columns have same column name, they form a data frame and another another 5 with same column name form another data frame.
2. Second: Find and `cbind()` duplicate column name columns into different data frames **if** the string of column name before `-` matches with the string of column name before `-` for another column **and** the string of column name after `-` **doesn't** match with part of column name after `-` for another column.

Below is the sample input data (the big data is too big, but follows exact same property), for which first two columns will form a single data frame based on above example. There will be another data frame that will contain columns starting three to the last one.

I tried `split()`, but that hasn't worked out so far. Any suggestions on how I can do this?

**Sample Input Data**

```
structure(list(`A-DIODE` = c(1.2, 0.4), `A-DIODE` = c(1.3, 0.6
), `B-DIODE` = c(1.4, 0.8), `B-ACC1` = c(1.5, 1), `B-ACC2` = c(1.6, 
1.2), `B-ANA0` = c(1.7, 1.4), `B-ANA1` = c(1.8, 1.6), `B-BRICKID` = c(1.9, 
1.8), `B-CC0` = c(2L, 2L), `B-CC1` = c(2.1, 2.2), `B-DIGDN` = c(2.2, 
2.4), `B-DIGDP` = c(2.3, 2.6), `B-DN1` = c(2.4, 2.8), `B-DN2` = c(2.5, 
3), `B-DP1` = c(2.6, 3.2), `B-DP2` = c(2.7, 3.4), `B-SCL` = c(2.8, 
3.6), `B-SDA` = c(2.9, 3.8), `B-USB0DN` = 3:4, `B-USB0DP` = c(3.1, 
4.2), `B-USB1DN` = c(3.2, 4.4), `B-USB1DP` = c(3.3, 4.6), `B-ACC1` = c(3.4, 
4.8), `B-ACC2` = c(3.5, 5), `B-ANA0` = c(3.6, 5.2), `B-ANA1` = c(3.7, 
5.4), `B-BRICKID` = c(3.8, 5.6), `B-CC0` = c(3.9, 5.8), `B-CC1` = c(4L, 
6L), `B-DIGDN` = c(4.1, 6.2), `B-DIGDP` = c(4.2, 6.4), `B-DN1` = c(4.3, 
6.6), `B-DN2` = c(4.4, 6.8), `B-DP1` = c(4.5, 7), `B-DP2` = c(4.6, 
7.2), `B-SCL` = c(4.7, 7.4), `B-SDA` = c(4.8, 7.6), `B-USB0DN` = c(4.9, 
7.8), `B-USB0DP` = c(5L, 8L), `B-USB1DN` = c(5.1, 8.2), `B-USB1DP` = c(5.2, 
8.4), `B-NA` = c(5.3, 8.6), `B-ACC2PWRLKG_0v4` = c(5.4, 8.8), 
`B-ACC2PWRLKG_0v4` = c(5.5, 9), `B-P_IN_Leak` = c(5.6, 9.2
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

**Output Based On Logic Discussed Above**

**Data Frame 1**

```
A-DIODE A-DIODE
1.2     1.3
0.4     0.6
```

**Data Frame 2**

```
B-DIODE B-ACC1 B-ACC2 B-ANA0 B-ANA1 B-BRICKID B-CC0 B-CC1 B-DIGDN B-DIGDP B-DN1 B-DN2 B-DP1 B-DP2 B-SCL B-SDA B-USB0DN B-USB0DP
1.4    1.5    1.6    1.7    1.8       1.9     2   2.1     2.2     2.3   2.4   2.5   2.6   2.7   2.8   2.9        3      3.1
0.8    1.0    1.2    1.4    1.6       1.8     2   2.2     2.4     2.6   2.8   3.0   3.2   3.4   3.6   3.8        4      4.2
B-USB1DN B-USB1DP B-ACC1.1 B-ACC2.1 B-ANA0.1 B-ANA1.1 B-BRICKID.1 B-CC0.1 B-CC1.1 B-DIGDN.1 B-DIGDP.1 B-DN1.1 B-DN2.1 B-DP1.1
3.2      3.3      3.4      3.5      3.6      3.7         3.8     3.9       4       4.1       4.2     4.3     4.4     4.5
4.4      4.6      4.8      5.0      5.2      5.4         5.6     5.8       6       6.2       6.4     6.6     6.8     7.0
B-DP2.1 B-SCL.1 B-SDA.1 B-USB0DN.1 B-USB0DP.1 B-USB1DN.1 B-USB1DP.1 B-NA B-ACC2PWRLKG_0v4 B-ACC2PWRLKG_0v4.1 B-P_IN_Leak
4.6     4.7     4.8        4.9          5        5.1        5.2  5.3              5.4                5.5         5.6
7.2     7.4     7.6        7.8          8        8.2        8.4  8.6              8.8                9.0         9.2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `split.default` on the substring of `names` of the dataset

```
split.default(df1, sub("-.*", "", names(df1)))
```

Or if we know there would be only one character before `-`

```
split.default(df1, substr(names(df1), 1, 1))
#$A
#  A-DIODE A-DIODE.1
#1     1.2       1.3
#2     0.4       0.6

#$B
#  B-DIODE B-ACC1 B-ACC2 B-ANA0 B-ANA1 B-BRICKID B-CC0 B-CC1 B-DIGDN B-DIGDP B-DN1 B-DN2 B-DP1 B-DP2 B-SCL B-SDA B-USB0DN B-USB0DP
#1     1.4    1.5    1.6    1.7    1.8       1.9     2   2.1     2.2     2.3   2.4   2.5   2.6   2.7   2.8   2.9        3      3.1
#2     0.8    1.0    1.2    1.4    1.6       1.8     2   2.2     2.4     2.6   2.8   3.0   3.2   3.4   3.6   3.8        4      4.2
#  B-USB1DN B-USB1DP B-ACC1.1 B-ACC2.1 B-ANA0.1 B-ANA1.1 B-BRICKID.1 B-CC0.1 B-CC1.1 B-DIGDN.1 B-DIGDP.1 B-DN1.1 B-DN2.1 B-DP1.1 B-DP2.1
#1      3.2      3.3      3.4      3.5      3.6      3.7         3.8     3.9       4       4.1       4.2     4.3     4.4     4.5     4.6
#2      4.4      4.6      4.8      5.0      5.2      5.4         5.6     5.8       6       6.2       6.4     6.6     6.8     7.0     7.2
#  B-SCL.1 B-SDA.1 B-USB0DN.1 B-USB0DP.1 B-USB1DN.1 B-USB1DP.1 B-NA B-ACC2PWRLKG_0v4 B-ACC2PWRLKG_0v4.1 B-P_IN_Leak
#1     4.7     4.8        4.9          5        5.1        5.2  5.3              5.4                5.5         5.6
#2     7.4     7.6        7.8          8        8.2        8.4  8.6              8.8                9.0         9.2
```

Comment: .@akrun - Thanks. In the sub data frames, is it possible to remove `.1` added at the end? If yes, then I want to remove all columns from sub data frame whose column name doesn't match with the first column of the sub data frame it belongs to.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil  It is possible, but I would advise to keep it that way because it would confuse which columns to choose if the names are the same

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil  By default, `data.frame` calls `make.names` which calls `make.unique` (if `check.names` is `TRUE`) to make the column names unique for a purpose.  If you want to keep the duplicate column  names then `lapply(split.default(df1, substr(names(df1), 1, 1)), function(x) setNames(x, sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(x))))`

Comment: .@akrun - Thanks. I want to keep duplicate columns in sub data frames, but only the first column if the sub data frame column name is unique in the sub data frame. Basically, I don't care (and that's why I want to keep column name same after `split.default` if even they are identical) what the third column name is in `$B` above, as 2nd column name doesn't match with 1st column name and this much pattern is enough for my data processing.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil  Then create an `if/else` condition to the above with `if(length(unique(sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(x)))) == 1) setNames(x, sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(x))) else x)`

Comment: .@akrun - Thanks, really appreciate your help. I am using `as.data.frame(df1[['A']])` to extract the first data frame from the data frame `list()` that gets created. Is there a better way to do this so that I extract all the data frames from list into different data frame variable at one go?

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil  I would keep this in list instead of creating multiple objects in the global environment.  If you really want to create objects, then change the `list` names with the names of the objects and then use `list2env` i.e. `list2env(setNames(lst1, c('newObj1','newObj2')), envir = .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: .@akrun - Thanks, I realized that. Hence I asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54562588/analyze-data-frames-in-a-list-and-bind-the-results).

Comment: .@akrun - To remove `.1` can I not apply it after the code `split.default(df1, sub("-.*", "", names(df1)))` you wrote in the answer? Looks like if I directly use `lapply(split.default(df1, substr(names(df1), 1, 1)), function(x) setNames(x, sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(x))))`, then it creates list of data frame based on string before `-`.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil  Yes, I meant it from the anonymous function call

Comment: .@akrun - Sorry, I am getting confused. After using `split.default(df1, sub("-.*", "", names(df1)))` what should I do to remove the `.1` from duplicate columns, so that I keep the same column name. Please note that the output of code I wrote is what I want to retain and then apply `.1` removal logic.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil  Lets say you assigned it to an identifier `lst1 <- split.default(df1, sub("-.*", "", names(df1)))` Now loop through the `lst1` with `lapply`  i.e. `lst2 <- lapply(lst1, function(x) setNames(x, sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(x))))`  Now, you can check 'lst2'  (based on the example)