# Analyze Data Frames In A List And Bind The Results

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data-analysis

The data I have is a list of data frames. I want to loop through each of the data frame to find:

1. If there are columns with duplicate column names. If yes, then I
   want to merge them by using `rbind()` in a parent data frame
   called `output` and remove all other columns of such data frames.
2. I also want to check if there is any data frame that doesn't have duplicate 
   columns. If yes, then remove all the columns except the first one. Then 
   `cbind()` with `output` such that if rows are more or less than what was 
   created by (1) then `zero` should be added.

I tried using `lappy()`, but my logic to get above two isn't working at one go. Any suggestion will help.

```
output <- lapply(data, function(x) {

})
```

**Input Data List Containing Data Frames**

```
list(A = structure(list(`A-DIODE` = c(1.2, 0.4), `A-DIODE` = c(1.3, 
0.6)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"), B = structure(list(
    `B-DIODE` = c(1.4, 0.8), `B-ACC1` = c(1.5, 1), `B-ACC2` = c(1.6, 
    1.2), `B-ANA0` = c(1.7, 1.4), `B-ANA1` = c(1.8, 1.6), `B-BRICKID` = c(1.9, 
    1.8), `B-CC0` = c(2L, 2L), `B-CC1` = c(2.1, 2.2), `B-DIGDN` = c(2.2, 
    2.4), `B-DIGDP` = c(2.3, 2.6), `B-DN1` = c(2.4, 2.8), `B-DN2` = c(2.5, 
    3), `B-DP1` = c(2.6, 3.2), `B-DP2` = c(2.7, 3.4), `B-SCL` = c(2.8, 
    3.6), `B-SDA` = c(2.9, 3.8), `B-USB0DN` = 3:4, `B-USB0DP` = c(3.1, 
    4.2), `B-USB1DN` = c(3.2, 4.4), `B-USB1DP` = c(3.3, 4.6), 
    `B-ACC1` = c(3.4, 4.8), `B-ACC2` = c(3.5, 5), `B-ANA0` = c(3.6, 
    5.2), `B-ANA1` = c(3.7, 5.4), `B-BRICKID` = c(3.8, 5.6), 
    `B-CC0` = c(3.9, 5.8), `B-CC1` = c(4L, 6L), `B-DIGDN` = c(4.1, 
    6.2), `B-DIGDP` = c(4.2, 6.4), `B-DN1` = c(4.3, 6.6), `B-DN2` = c(4.4, 
    6.8), `B-DP1` = c(4.5, 7), `B-DP2` = c(4.6, 7.2), `B-SCL` = c(4.7, 
    7.4), `B-SDA` = c(4.8, 7.6), `B-USB0DN` = c(4.9, 7.8), `B-USB0DP` = c(5L, 
    8L), `B-USB1DN` = c(5.1, 8.2), `B-USB1DP` = c(5.2, 8.4), 
    `B-NA` = c(5.3, 8.6), `B-ACC2PWRLKG_0v4` = c(5.4, 8.8), `B-ACC2PWRLKG_0v4` = c(5.5, 
    9), `B-P_IN_Leak` = c(5.6, 9.2)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"))
```

**Desired Output**

```
> A
  A-DIODE
    1.2
    0.4
    1.3
    0.6

> B
  B-DIODE
    1.4 
    0.8

> Output
  A-DIODE B-DIODE
    1.2     1.4
    0.4     0.8
    1.3      0
    0.6      0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through the `list`, create a condition with `if/else` that checks the `length` of the `unique` column names and returns the `unlist`ed single data.frame when there is only a single unique column or else return the first column.  Finally, with `cbind.fill` (from `rowr`) bind the `list` of `data.frame` columns together, specifying the `fill` as 0

```
lst2 <- lapply(lst1, function(x) if(length(unique(names(x))) ==1)
     setNames(data.frame(unlist(x)), names(x)[1]) else x[1])
do.call(rowr::cbind.fill, c(lst2, list(fill = 0)))
#    A.DIODE B.DIODE
#1     1.2     1.4
#2     0.4     0.8
#3     1.3     0.0
#4     0.6     0.0
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188197/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-analyze-data-frames-in-a-list-and-bind-the-results). Please remember to update the answer with any insights gleaned from the discussion.